# Unable to connect to DHCP after using VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, ethernet, dhcp

I used a VPN to play a game I was having some issues with.

After uninstalling the VPN I have had some issues connecting to the internet & my local network on a Ethernet connection, wireless works fine.

I have Googled extensively to no avail.

What I have noticed is that when running ipconfig, no default gateway is set & the IP address looks private.

When trying to run `ipconfig /release` & `ipconfig /renew` I get this error:

> An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet : unable to contact your DHCP server. Request time out.

Any ideas what could be happening here? Or what I can do just to vanilla my network?

I should add. It does not seem to be an issue with my PC - it happens to any device connected to the router via Ethernet.

I should also mention that between the router and device I use Devolo wall plug adaptors. Router -> Devolo -> Devolo -> Device

Comment: Can you add the output of your network state 1) After a clean boot. 2) After starting the VPN.  3) At the time you get this problem. And include if (3) is at a time where you disconnected from the VPN or if the renew happens while still on the VPN.

Answer (score 0):

Windows default network adapter settings try to get IP- and Gateway-Address from DHCP-Server. So check network adapter settings first.

If the issue happens to all computers connected via Ethernet, I think it does not relate to the VPN-connection you installed but to the router itself.
What router model do you have?

Can you try a different router to check if your computers will receive IP-/Gateway-/DNS-Server-Address? Almost IP and Gateway should be received also if this router is not connected to the internet.

Otherwise try what happens if you manually edit your computers IP-Settings. You will need IP and Subnet to ping your router. For internet access you will need Gateway and DNS-Server.

Comment: I am unable to try a difference router. The router is BT Home Hub 3.

I should also mention that between the router and device I use Devolo wall plug adaptors. Router -> Devolo -> Devolo -> Device

Comment: Well, you have to try a few things to find the faulty device. If other computers have the same problems to connect to your network, than the VPN-thing probably will not be the problem.
Take your computer near to the router and connect it directly to the router without the Devolo adapters.
Did you try manual IP-Settings?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)